# Issues with DateTime DataType

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL 5.1 server community edition database. In a table I have a column with the name TransactionDate of **DateTime** DataType. Each time a new insert is done, this column value is updated with the current Date and Time values.

When I created this table, I expected a unique seconds value with every insert. In some strange scenarios, MySQL is storing same Date/Time values. This is making few reports to crash. It is strange because the user has to fill a Form and it takes a couple of minutes. When the user saves a new record, current Date/Time values are stored in the TransactionDate column. There is no question of duplicate values as, at least, seconds will change.

Please suggest any better ways to handle this problem.

Comment: Do the entries with the duplicated date/time have other data duplicated?  It could be a double submission in that case, such as from the form being sent twice (e.g. a double click rather than a single click somewhere).

Comment: The issue is probably in your application logic. Perhaps you're using extended inserts (a.k.a multi row inserts) or update several rows at once using table joins.
Also, take a look at TIMESTAMP datatype and how can it be used to default to row insert time.

Comment: @borrible: No. Only in that column.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a unique date/time, use the trigger to populate it automatically with `now()` when the row is created.

Bonus... Here's a working trigger definition:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER MYTABLE_INSERT_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON MYTABLE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    SET NEW.TransactionDate = now();
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: How's that better from TIMESTAMP?